# iis7 Web Site ASP.NET MVC4 config session expired

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, iis, iis-7

I have a Web Site with ASP.NET MVC 4 and razor.
I would not like users session expired, I config in webconfig, I set the session for that expired after a day.
In my web config I have this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/raLogin/Login" timeout="1440"/>
</authentication>
....
....
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1440" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

But the session expired in 20 minutes!!
Then I config IIS 7 (windows server 2008)
I installed MS FW 4.0 and execute aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
In Application Pool in ASP.NET v4 Classic I set this values (see image):
[image]

but the session expired in 20 minutes
The site web in iss 7 I set this values:
[image]

How I can setup my website so the session expires after a day?

Comment: This is a bad idea.  Anything you put in session will stay in memory until the session expires, or the app pool is recycled.  So this can be a source of memory leaks, as objects won't be garbage collected.  Also, you cannot depend on this, since the app pool can be recycled at any time by IIS (and you can't prevent it) so you should write your app to not depend on session being available, even if you've just logged in.. Cause it could go away at any time.  You need to be able to re-create anything in session if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a persisted, out of process state mechanism backed by SQLServer. As Erik points you may want to review the data you are trying to persist as session variables may not be the optimal location.

Explanation of state mechanisms and instruction on configuration:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx

Review of InProc, StateServer and SQLServer performance:
http://www.nullskull.com/a/1611/aspnet-session-how-to-faqs.aspx

If you really want to get fancy you can use what the big boy's use, distributed in memory cache such as AppFabric:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859(v=azure.10).aspx